# Selenium Webdriver Loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, selenium, webdriver

I have an array within my test case which is then passed into another string to select a random item from the array.

I'm having a problem whereby when this array is called within a loop, the same value from the array is chosen each time.

Here is the array in question - this sits within a base class.

```
private String asapSelector = "#main-view > div > section:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > radio-button-collection > custom-radio-button:nth-child(1) > label";
private String laterSelector = "#main-view > div > section:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > radio-button-collection > custom-radio-button:nth-child(2) > label";
String [] dateAndTime = {asapSelector, laterSelector}; //DATE & TIME ARRAY
String randomDateAndTime = (dateAndTime[new Random().nextInt(dateAndTime.length)]); //SELECT RANDOM DATE & TIME FROM ARRAY
```

Also, the method which calls 'randomDateAndTime' sits within the base class and looks like

```
protected void selectDateTimeRadio() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(randomDateAndTime)).click(); //fix
        if(randomDateAndTime.equals(asapSelector)) {
            System.out.println("DATE & TIME: ASAP selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("I need to add more 'Later' specific tests here...");
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'hasDatepicker')]")).sendKeys("19/08/2017 00:00");
            System.out.println("DATE & TIME: Later selected");
        }
}
```

Within my test case, I extend the base class, and call the method, which looks like

```
public class makeBooking extends makeBookingBase {

    @Test
    public void makeNewBooking() throws Throwable {

        for (String scope: vehicleType) {
            openEnvironment();
            selectOnBehalfOf("Tommy");
            selectLeadPassenger("Bobby");
            selectNumberOfPassengers();
            selectJourneyTypeRadio();
            selectDateTimeRadio(); //THE METHOD IM STUCK WITH IS CALLED HERE!
                if(!scope.equals("disabled")) {
                    selectVehicleType(scope);
                }
                else {
                    selectVehicleType(scope);
                    selectWheelchairType();
                }
            clickReviewButton();
        }
    }
}
```

As previously mentioned above, I'm having a problem whereby the same value from the array (scope in this instance) is being used for each loop (vehicleType in this instance)

Is there a way to generate a new value of the array for each instance of the loop? If possible, can you please explain below.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess randomDateAndTime is a class variable and its value is set once the class has been initiated and it will have the same value thorough. Can you put that variable inside a method and return the random every time the method has been called?

Comment: @santhoshkumar Thank you! What a simple solution, worked fine :)

Comment: Im. not sure if I understand but driver has method to find multiple elements and you can random them.  driver.findElements(byClass("radioDate"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `randomDateAndTime` have a class variable and its value have been set once the class has been initiated and it will have the same value thorough. I suggest to put that variable inside a method and return the random every time the method has been called.

Hope this helps. Thanks.